# How is communication between two computers without port forwarding possible?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic

I'm working on a project in which I have to send information between computers over the internet. Usually the obvious solution to assure there isn't much fuzz in the way would be port-forwarding. However, I noticed applications like Skype are able to open connections such as these without making the user port forward (in most cases). I noticed this when you are able to retrieve the IP of the person on the other end of the call using a tool such as netstat.

So my question is: How does Skype, and the "other" applications, manage to do this? How open is a "common" router?

Note: I haven't read much about networking and this might be trivial but if you do have any good reads on the subject or anything related to networking, I would be thankful.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Probably, where should I ask? I tried security but I got the same response.

Answer (score 2):

Skype uses a technique called "hole punching" to get through firewalls.

I wrote a long description [here](http://www.acooke.org/cute/WhatisTCPh1.html).  From that:

> In general, hole punching requires the following:
>
> - An external, public server that is the target for initial connections, and    which helps coordinate the connection process.
> - Two peers behind NAT, who will eventually be connected directly.
> - NAT implementations that are lenient in the traffic that they accept, and    which are predictable in how they operate.
> - A protocol (like TCP) which is lenient in the traffic it accepts and     which, in particular, uses a state machine and messages that
>   are more     symmetric than the server / client roles that are assumed
>   at a higher    level.
>
> The general process (bearing in mind that this is only a rough sketch)
> for hole punching is:
>
> - Peers connect to a central, public server and agree on which pairs will    connect.
> - The central server identifies, for each NAT, how future outgoing     connections are created (when a peer makes a connection that passes
>   through the NAT then a port must be opened on on the NAT to receive
>   the     response; typically the port numbers used are sequential).

(Actually, the details above are for TCP hole punching.  It's possible Skype uses UDP, but the general idea is similar).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, apparently this is done using an intermediary server which brokers the connection.